# Restricting last item value in python list to a given date

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a list using a given start and end date range in a specific format. I would like to have the elements in the list incremented by 30 days. The last item in the list should not exceed the end date that i have set.

With the logic that I have below, it exceeds the end date that i have set.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

start_date = date(2021,1,1)
end_date = date(2021,6,30)

n = 30

next_date = start_date
res = []

while start_date < end_date:
    next_date = (start_date + timedelta(n))
    next_date_str = next_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    var = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'#'+next_date_str

    res.append(var)
    start_date = next_date + timedelta(1)

print(res)
```

**Result of above code:**

```
['2022-01-01#2022-01-31', '2022-02-01#2022-03-03', '2022-03-04#2022-04-03', '2022-04-04#2022-05-04', '2022-05-05#2022-06-04', '2022-06-05#2022-07-05']
```

**Expected output:**

```
['2022-01-01#2022-01-31', '2022-02-01#2022-03-03', '2022-03-04#2022-04-03', '2022-04-04#2022-05-04', '2022-05-05#2022-06-04', '2022-06-05#2022-06-30']
```

Please guide me how to restrict the end date for the list

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this problem would be to add a check to your while loop to check if the next date is greater than the end date. If it is, you can set the next date to the end date, and then break out of the loop.

Here's how you could update your code to do this:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

start_date = date(2021,1,1)
end_date = date(2021,6,30)

n = 30

next_date = start_date
res = []

while start_date < end_date:
next_date = (start_date + timedelta(n))
if next_date > end_date:
    next_date = end_date
    break

next_date_str = next_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
var = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'#'+next_date_str

res.append(var)
start_date = next_date + timedelta(1)

print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Could you please format the answer? The indentations seems to be off